# Singleton clarification

Tags: java, singleton

I have a question for better understanding Singleton pattern in Java. Particularly, I'm interested in private static variable which is instance of the class whose static variable it is. My problem is to understand what happens when you instantiate that static variable with private constructor. That object is instance of a class whose instance variable it is, but that means that inside that object is another instance of that class, inside of which is another, etc. To test that, I wrote next code:

```
public class SingletonTest {
private static SingletonTest s=new SingletonTest();
int x=0;

private SingletonTest(){}


public static void increase(int y){
    s.x=s.x+y;
}


public static void main(String [] args){

    SingletonTest.increase(5);
    System.out.println(SingletonTest.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.x);

}
}
```

It printed out 5. Which means there is object inside object inside object, etc. because there is SingletonTest.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.s.x variable with its value. Any clarification what actually happens when line

```
private static SingletonTest s=new SingletonTest();
```

is executed? How many objects inside objects are created? It should be infinite, but that's impossible.  Since the upper code worked there must be many.Singleton should produce only one object, but that's not the case because inside every instance is another. And why this code produced output 5 when only s.x is increased, not s.s.s....s.x? Every object inside object should have his own x. Thanks for any clarification on this matter.

Comment: The is one single object and he is shared class-wide.

Comment: "Which means there is object inside object inside object" No, you're just accessing a static variable through an instance, which is allowed but error-prone.

Comment: Please note that if you want to implement a true singleton you need to make final your variable  s to prevent any further modification, in other words it should be private static final SingletonTest s=new SingletonTest();

Answer (score 0):

you define this:

```
private static SingletonTest s=new SingletonTest();
```

so that is an static object and is going to be created only once, so when you do

`SingletonTest.s.s.s.s.s.s....` you are getting over and over the static instance of **SingletonTest** but the object was per se created only once.

Comment: But inside that static object (since it is made on SingletonTest class blueprint) should be one instance variable x and another instance variable s which is again object, and inside that object should be another x and another object s... If not, if there's only one, class wide object as instance variable, what is inside that object in place of instance variables x and s, especially s?

Comment: @Seba - just changed my answer. Take a look.

Comment: seen, thanks... tried to comment, but comment was too long, so I posted it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Trying to clarify... you are accessing the same instance over and over again. A similar situation (not using static members for simplicity) is this:

```
class Recursive {
    public Recursive me;
    private String message = "sayHello";

    public Recursive() {
        me = this;
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

}
```

The Recursive object holds a reference for himself. I can call *me* over and over but there is one single instance:

```
Recursive rec = new Recursive();
rec.me.me.me.me.me.sayHello();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer, but, your answer doesn't really cover what I tried to ask... In my lines, constructor is called in same line where instance variable is defined...
Your code avoided that...
code:

```
public class RekurzivTester {
public  RekurzivTester r=new RekurzivTester();
private RekurzivTester(){}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RekurzivTester rek=new RekurzivTester();
}
}
```

produces stack overflow error. My explanation is that it's because when new object in main() was produced, infinite chain of object-inside-object was triggered, but if you add static to the second line, no more stack overflow error. Explanation is that there is only one object per class which is accessed with rek.r, rek.r.r., etc.,  but still, since statement rek.r.r.r.r.r.r.... has sense, it means that there is still inside r another r inside of which is another, etc. (to infinity), but they all access the same object which is class wide.
am I right?